# How to remove line when no data for some time in real time plot using corePlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am drawing a real time plot using `corePlot`.There I should not connect two points if there is no data at that instance, but by using `corePlot`, the line automatically connecting all points.

Is there any way to stop line draw between two desired points

[image]